# ReactJS not updating the state

Tags: reactjs, stackblitz

Hello for some reason React would not update the state globally,

```
  componentDidMount() {
    var id = window.location.href.split('/')[3]
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://reactAppBackend/edit/" + id);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onloadend = () => {
      this.setState({singlePost: JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)})
      console.log(this.state.singlePost[0])
    };
  }
```

when I run this the console log return data this data

```
{_id: "5e6016adb8c32b00883f55f5", postTitle: "RE4", postContent: "the best ", __v: 0}
```

but when I try to render the state:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.singlePost[0]}</div>
    )
  }
```

it is not rendering anything.

Comment: `componentDidMount` is not an async function

Comment: when I change the state so for example it is working

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo inside your render. It's should be singlePost

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.singlePost[0]}</div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here: `<div>{this.state.siglePost[0]}</div>`

siglePost, should be singlePost

Answer (score 0):

The state was an array, I have managed to show the response with the map function.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.singlePost.map(post => {
          return (
            <div>
              <p>{post.postTitle}</p>
              <p>{post.postContent}</p>
              <img src={post.postPicturePath} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```